# how compare two static function are equal or not in javascript

Tags: javascript

how to compare two static functions in javascript equal or not equal?

Comment: why do you want to compare them?

Answer (score 6):

```
String(f1) === String(f2)
```

Comment: I think you mean `String(f1) === String(f2)` unless you have a custom `string()` method that I'm unaware of :)

Comment: Another way of writing it, for the byte-savers out there: `""+f1 === ""+f2`

Comment: Does it work with `(String(f1.bind(this)) === String(f1.bind(this)))`? I think not?

Answer (score 6):

```
var f1 = f2 = function( a ){ return a; };
```

here, you can use `f1 === f2` because they're pointing to the same memory and they're the same type

```
var f1 = function( a ){ return a; },
    f2 = function( a ){ return a; };
```

here you can use that byte-saver Andy E used (which is implicitly converting the function to it's body's text as a String),

`''+f1 == ''+f2`.

this is the gist of what is happening behind the scences:

```
f1.toString( ) == f2.toString( )
```

---

**Edit: Looking back on this post over a year after, I agree with @kangax - you should probably never do this.**

Comment: +1 for a more elaborate answer

Comment: haha, but it is your answer ...
I just don't know how much JavaScript black magic the author has done (like we have) before, :P

Comment: Note that `var f1 = f2 = function(){ ... }` results in `f2` becoming a global property, due to undeclared assignment of function to `f2`. Undeclared assignments are generally harmful, so it's better to avoid that pattern. Also, don't rely on `Function.prototype.toString` — it's not standardized and varies across browsers.

Comment: I just tested the above code in IE 6, 7, 8, FF 2, 3.0, 3.5 (Windows / Linux), Opera 10 (Windows / Linux), Safari 4, and Chrome (Windows / Linux).

Which browsers do you develop for exactly?  Konqueror, haha?

here's the code, someone prove me wrong `javascript:(function(){var f1=function(a){return a;},f2=function(a){return a;};alert(f1.toString());alert(f2.toString());alert(""+f1==""+f2);})();`

Comment: Here are few I stumbled upon — http://perfectionkills.com/those-tricky-functions/ , so not something I would rely on. YMMV, of course ;)

Comment: you're only comparing them to eachother in *the same browser*, so how the functions look **across browsers** is not really that helpful, but I appreciate your time taken to compile that list and will remember these flaws.

Comment: But Blackberry, for example, always returns *same representation for any 2 different function*. Doesn't that prove this approach unreliable? I also remember cases of Opera mini doing similar thing. This all makes perfect sense in environments like mobile phone browsers, where there's a limited amount of memory available (and so keeping representation of functions is rather wasteful, especially that specs do not put any restrictions on what `Function.prototype.toString` returns ;))

Comment: Then, yes, you are right kangax.  If all functions look the same when their .toString( ) function is called on BlackBerry, you're right not to use it in your mobile app.  Do you have a better solution, or just that it's not really possible?

Comment: I simply try to avoid design which would lead to using function decompilation. You can certainly decompile functions when working in closed environments (e.g. in intranet apps) or for debugging/profiling purposes (during development). Anything that's meant for public web is better left without it, and, as a result, have less chances of blowing up in some less-common environments.

Comment: yes, I agree.  too bad the author may not, :(

Comment: @kangax - I lol'ed that Prototype is actually doing this, then (from the source) - https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/master/src/prototype/lang/function.js#L20

Comment: This won't work when comparing 2 same functions which has different scope applied to them via the `bind()` method. this is problematic

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to compare functions I make sure there is no scope ambiguity and use the same function object.

Say I have some a pair of library functions that take a callback as one of the parameters. For the sake of this example `create1minuteCallback` function will set a 1 minute timer and call the callback on each tick. `kill1minuteCallback` will turn off the callback and you must pass the same callback function as you did for `create1minuteCallback`.

```
function create1minuteCallback(callback){
//implementation
}

function kill1minuteCallback(callback){
//implementation
}
```

Quite clearly this will not work as the function we are passing is different on the second line:

```
create1minuteCallback(function(){alert("1 minute callback is called");});
kill1minuteCallback(function(){alert("1 minute callback is called");});
```

I normally do this:

```
function callbackFunc(){alert("1 minute callback is called");}

create1minuteCallback(callbackFunc);
kill1minuteCallback(callbackFunc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as simply as that - if you are going to compare functions, you do it for a reason I assume. What is your reason?
My reason was to not run a certain function twice.
I did it this way (just snippet code to get the idea)

```
   var x = function(){
    console.error("i am a functionX");
  }
   var y = function(){
        console.error("i am a functionX");



  }

    var z = function(){
       console.error("i am a functionZ");



  }
       var x2= x;

   var obj = new Object();
    obj[x] = "";
    obj[x2] = "";
    obj[y] = "";
    obj[z] = "";
    obj.abc = "xaxa";
                for (prop in obj) {
                    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                      console.error(obj[prop] + " hello " + prop);
                    }
            }
```

Function x and y are the same, even though they have different whitespaces. x and y are not the same as z, since z has a different console.error.
[Btw open your firebug console to see it in the jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/uderet/1/edit)